# Hyperledger fabric Is it possible to re-genrate the keypair

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am working in project using the Hyperledger fabric.

If the member lost his key pair and certificate is it possible to regenerate it?

Is it possible to sign the transaction with plain text "Eg: can sign the transaction hello world"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, he must enroll new certificate from the CA using its username/password. If he forgets its username/password, he requires the intervention of the CA admin.
2. No idea what are you referring to. You sign with a private key and valid certificate. I would say no.

Comment: thanks for replay, in ethereum and tendermint we can take any-kind of data {data can be : hello word or anything}sign the transaction and can send it.Is it possible to sign any kind of data and send has transaction in hyperledger fabric

Comment: In Ethereum you sign with any ECDSA private key that match a public key (and thus its address). Other thing is that you use a seed phrase to generate keys. Your transaction in Fabric must be signed in its source with a valid (as provided by a valid CA) private key (and certificate). Then, some peers must execute and sign the transaction as defined by endorsement policies. Finally an orderer build a block with the endorsed transaction and signs that block.